# Adjust picture size according to table width in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

When inserting a picture into a table the picture exceeds the table width. I can achieve making it fit into the table by resizing it manually. I was wondering if there is anything like a "fit to table" option though.

Answer (score 1):

It should fit the picture automatically inside the table.
Let's try something then. 
Create a table. Right-click on the table and choose '*Table Properties*' and in the '*Table*' tab choose '*Options..*' and see if the '*Automatically resize to fit contents*' is checked.

If you're pasting the picture, rather than inserting it through *Insert* - *Picture*, you can right-click the picture and choose *Wrap Text* - *Tight* or *Square*. Also, by right-clicking  on the table again and go to *Table Properties* you can edit the indent to 0, to fit it better inside the table.

Comment: They are asking about Word, not Excel.

Comment: I swear I read that as Excel and not just once :P Editing it now so it answers the question correctly