# Fit text to shape in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I set a piece of text to autofit to the size of the textbox, so that when I add or delete text it will automatically fill the textbox?
I used to grow or shrink size accordingly each time but it takes to long, I want to just set it to automatically resize.

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for is called "Autofit" in Office.

Unfortunately Word has no such option, although Publisher does have it
([documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fit-text-in-a-text-box-527b8224-45ca-4d40-a6d6-5d3430af33c3)).

The Autofit commands in Word are for tables, as you may see in the
"Customize Ribbon" dialog :

[image]

So unfortunately, there is no answer to your question.

Comment: I suspected so, but I think I might have seen it done using word art?

Comment: Yes, Word Art is graphic so it can be resized. It's also always in autofit mode.

Comment: So how can i do that please

Comment: You will need to continue doing it the manual way. Luckily, Word when hovering over the list of font sizes, now shows the text with the size that is below the cursor. This makes it easier to find the right size. The most you could do is use the Feedback Hub to complain to Microsoft, but I assume that you won't be the first one to have done so.

Comment: Sorry I meant how can I do that with wordart

Comment: My experience is that all you have to do is select the shape and drag the little circles in the frame.

Comment: you mean the circles to adjust the size?

Comment: Yes, the usual term is "drag handles".

Comment: that just changes the size of the textbox it doesn't do anything to the text

Comment: You're sure you're using wordart, or is there some misunderstanding here.

Comment: I have a text box with text inside, i selected all the text and then clicked insert word art, which then made a new textbox with the same content on top of the old one. I assume that the new textbox is a word art

Comment: I understand now. The wordart is completely resizable, because it's just an image, but its size is independent from that of the textbox. Resizing the textbox doesn't affect the wordart, and resizing the wordart can even make it larger than the textbox (the overflow will be hidden). As far as the textbox itself is concerned, the answer is still that it doesn't do autofit. The Microsoft developers just didn't do it for Word (although they did for Publisher).

Comment: I understand that but i think for my purposes word art will do fine, but i dont see how to change the size

Comment: You can do it inside a table : [link](https://superuser.com/questions/597990/adjust-picture-size-according-to-table-width-in-word-2010).

Comment: So i return to the question; How can i, using word art, create a textbox or something similar, with text inside, that the text will automatically fill the box, expanding or contracting accordingly?